# Is this sequence increasing or decreasing? Is it bounded? How do I more formally show the bound?

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have this general equation for a sequence:

$$a_n = \frac{1-n}{2+n}$$

is it increasing or decraesing? Writing out the first few terms I have:

$${0, \frac{-1}{4}, \frac{-2}{5},\frac{-3}{6},\frac{-4}{7},\frac{-5}{8}}$$

using a derivative test, we get:

$$f(x)= \frac{1-x}{2+x}$$

$$f'(x)= -1$$

so the sequence is decraesing as $n -> \infty$

Since the first term is 0, it's bounded above by 0. And it looks like it never crosses -1 so it's bounded below by -1. But how do I show this more vigorously?

Taking the limits seems like half the answer. What if the function oscillates around the limit but cross it? Taking the limit doesn't seem like the complete way to find the bounds right?

Comment: Show $a_{n+1}-a_n < 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Write it as $a_n=-1+\frac 3{2+n}$ and it is clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$a_n = \frac{1-n}{2+n} = \frac{-2-n+3}{2+n} = -1 + \frac{3}{2+n} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Thus, for $n \gt -2$, $a_n \gt -1$. Also, this allows you to determine that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = -1$ since $\frac{3}{2+n}$ goes to $0$.